# Can't print dots after authors names when using gost780s citation package

Tags: bibtex

Writing thesis in Math, I use ProTex and citation package called GOST (file `gost780s.bst`) by Igor Kotelnikov. Problem is when I build PDF, not all the dots after the journal author`s name initials are produced. I have tried to produce bibtex and pdflatex several times, but some citations are not OK.

It looks like: Author, J. Name of work. // JF AuthorOne, JH Author // Journal name - Year....

And I need initials like J.F., J.H.

Is there any PDF editor to put the dots in PDFLatex or a tool for converting MathType embedded equations to a clean Word? I have tried Infty and NitroPDF but results are not perfect.

Thank you, I hope you understand the question and can help

Here is `.bst` file code:

```
%%
%% This is file `gost780s.bst',
%% generated with the docstrip utility.
%%
%% The original source files were:
%%
%% gost.dtx  (with options: `bst,sort')
%% 
%% This file may be distributed and/or modified under the
%% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either version 1.3
%% of this license or (at your option) any later version.
%% The latest version of this license is in
%%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.3 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 2005/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% This file has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%% Maintained by Igor A. Kotelnikov.
%% Current version: 2012.02.02
%% 
%% Please, send bug report via e-mail:
%%   kia999 at mail dot ru <Igor Kotelnikov>
%% or
%%   polyama at yahoo dot com <Maksym Polyakov>
%% 



%%
%% This bibstyle attempts to format bibliography according to
%% GOST 7.80-2000 for bibliographic records.

ENTRY
  { address
    annote
    author
    booktitle
    bookauthor
    chapter
    edition
    editor
    compiler
    howpublished
    institution
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    medium % new in v.2.
    type
    volume
    year
    language
    booklanguage
    numpages
    url
    urldate
    isbn
    doi
    eprinttype   % = archivePrefix
    eprintclass  % = primaryClass
    eprint
  }
  {}
  { label }

INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block
after.dblslash after.slash after.column after.semicolumn }

FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
  #4 'after.dblslash :=
  #5 'after.slash :=
  #6 'after.column :=
  #7 'after.semicolumn :=
}

STRINGS { s t }

STRINGS { curlanguage }

FUNCTION {change.language}
{ booklanguage empty$
    { "" }
    { booklanguage  'curlanguage :=
      "\selectlanguageifdefined{"
      curlanguage *
      "}" *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{
  swap$
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          " " quote$ "--- " * *  write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { output.state after.dblslash =
                { "~//" * change.language * " " * write$ }
                { output.state after.slash =
                    { "~/ " * write$ }
                    { output.state after.column =
                        { ": " * write$ }
                        { output.state after.semicolumn =
                            { "; " * write$ }
                        { add.period$ " " * write$ }
                       if$
                        }
                      if$
                    }
                  if$
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}

FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.dblslash}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.dblslash 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.slash}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.slash 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.column}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.column 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.semicolumn}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.semicolumn 'output.state := }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {add.blank}
{ " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}

INTEGERS { len }

FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}

FUNCTION {non.stop}
{ duplicate$
   "}" * add.period$
   #-1 #1 substring$ "." =
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.sentence.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.sentence
  if$
}

FUNCTION {new.dblslash.checka}
{ empty$
    'skip$
    'new.dblslash
  if$
}

FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}

FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\BibEmph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {enclose.square.brackets} { }

FUNCTION {bracify}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "{}" }
    { "{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bracketise}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "[]" }
    { "[" swap$ * "]" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {parenthesify}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "()" }
    { "(" swap$ * ")" * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {space.word}
{ " " swap$ * " " * }

FUNCTION {bbl.edby}    %  { "\bbledby{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"Ed.\ by"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
      {"{\cyr\CYRP\cyrii\cyrd\ \cyrr\cyre\cyrd.}"}
      { curlanguage "russian" =
         {"{\cyr\CYRP\cyro\cyrd\ \cyrr\cyre\cyrd.}"}
         { curlanguage "german" =
            { "ed." }
            {"language is not defined: " language "edby" * * warning$ "Ed.\ by"}
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.cmplr}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "Compiler"}
   { curlanguage "german" =
      { "Hrsg." }
      { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
         {"{\cyr\CYRU\cyrk\cyrl.}"}
         { curlanguage "russian" =
            {"{\cyr\CYRS\cyro\cyrs\cyrt.}"}
            {"language is not defined: " language  "cmplr" * * warning$ "Compiler"}
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.edition} %  { "\bbledition{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"edition"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
      {"{\cyr\cyrv\cyri\cyrd.}"}
      { curlanguage "russian" =
         {"{\cyr\cyri\cyrz\cyrd.}"}
         { curlanguage "german" =
            {" {aus.}" } %%%% { "Aufl." } ??
            { curlanguage "italian" =
               {"edizione"}
               { curlanguage "french" =
                  {"\'{e}dition"}
                  {"language is not defined: " language  "edition" * * warning$ "edition"}
               if$}
            if$}
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.vvolume} %  { "\bblVolume{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" = curlanguage "french" = or curlanguage "italian" = or
   {"Volume"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      { "\CYRT\cyro\cyrm" }
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"{Band}"} %%%% { "Volumen" }
         {"language is not defined: " language  "vvolume" * * warning$ "Volume"}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.vvol}    %  { "\bblVol{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" = curlanguage "french" = or curlanguage "italian" = or
   {"Vol."}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      {"\CYRT."}
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"{Bd.}"} %%%% { "Vol." }
         {"language is not defined: " language  "vvol" * * warning$ "Vol."}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.iissue}  %  { "\bblIssue{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"Issue"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
      {"\CYRV\cyri\cyrp\cyru\cyrs\cyrk"}
      { curlanguage "russian" =
         {"\CYRV\cyrery\cyrp\cyru\cyrs\cyrk"}
         { curlanguage "german" =
            {"{Heft}"} %%%% { "Ausgabe" }
            {"language is not defined: " language "iissue" * * warning$ "Issue"}
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.iiss}  %  { "\bblIss{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"Iss."}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
      {"\CYRV\cyri\cyrp."}
      { curlanguage "russian" =
         {"\CYRV\cyrery\cyrp."}
         { curlanguage "german" =
            {"{H.}"}
            {"language is not defined: " language "iiss" * * warning$ "Iss."}
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.of}      %  { "\bblof{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"of"}
   { curlanguage "german" =
      { "von" }
      { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
         { "{\cyr\cyrii\cyrz}" }
         { curlanguage "russian" =
            { "{\cyr\cyri\cyrz}" }
            {"language is not defined: " language "of" * * warning$ "of"}
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.etal}      %  { "\bblof{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"et~al."}
   { curlanguage "german" =
      { "u.~a." }
      { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
         {"{\cyr\cyrt\cyra~\cyrii\cyrn.}"}
         { curlanguage "russian" =
            {"{\cyr\cyri~\cyrd\cyrr.}"}
            {"language is not defined: " language  "et~al" * * warning$ "et~al."}
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}


FUNCTION {bbl.nnumber} %  { "\bblNumber{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"Number"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      { "\CYRN\cyro\cyrm\cyre\cyrr" }
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"{Heft}"} %%% { "Anzahl" }
         {"language is not defined: " language  "nnumber" * * warning$ "Number"}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.number}  %  { "\bblnumber{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"number"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      {"{\cyr\cyrn\cyro\cyrm\cyre\cyrr}"}
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"{Heft}"} %%% { "anzahl" }???
         {"language is not defined: " language  "number" * * warning$ "number"}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.nr}     %   { "\bblno{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"№"}                     %change here
   { curlanguage "italian" =
      { "no" }
      { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
         { "{\cyr\textnumero}" }
         { curlanguage "german" =
            {"{H.}"} %%% { "an." }
            {"language is not defined: " language "nr" * * warning$ "№"}
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.nnr}     %   { "\bblno{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"№"}                            % сhange here
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      { "{\cyr\textnumero}" }
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"{H.}"} %%% { "an." }
         {"language is not defined: " language  "nnr" * * warning$ "№"}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.in}    %    { "\bblin{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" = curlanguage "german" = or
   {"in"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      { "{\cyr\cyrv}" }
      {"language is not defined: " language  "in" * * warning$ "in"}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.iin}  %     { "\bblIn{}" }
{ curlanguage "english" = curlanguage "german" = or
   {"In"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      { "\CYRV" }
      {"language is not defined: " language  "iin" * * warning$ "In"}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.pages}    % { "\bblpp." }
{ curlanguage "english" = curlanguage "french" = or curlanguage "italian" = or
   {"p."} %%% {"pp."}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      {"{\cyr\cyrs.}"}
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"S."} %%%% { "s." }
         {"language is not defined: " language  "pages" * * warning$ "p."}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.page}   %   { "\bblp."
{ curlanguage "english" = curlanguage "french" = or curlanguage "italian" = or
   {"p."}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      {"{\cyr\cyrs.}"}
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"S."} %%%% { "s." }
         {"language is not defined: " language  "page" * * warning$ "p."}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.ppages}%    { "\bblPp." }
{ curlanguage "english" = curlanguage "french" = or curlanguage "italian" = or
   {"P."} %%%% { "Pp." }
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      {"{\cyr\CYRS.}"}
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"S."}
         {"language is not defined: " language "ppages" * * warning$ "P."}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.ppage}  %   { "\bblP." }
{ curlanguage "english" = curlanguage "french" = or curlanguage "italian" = or
   {"P."}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" = curlanguage "russian" = or
      {"{\cyr\CYRS.}"}
      { curlanguage "german" =
         {"S."}
         {"language is not defined: " language  "ppage" * * warning$ "P."}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.urldate}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   {"online; accessed"}
   { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
      { "{\cyrd\cyra\cyrt\cyra\ \cyrz\cyrv\cyre\cyrr\cyrn\cyre\cyrn\cyrn\cyrya}" }
      { curlanguage "russian" =
         { "{\cyrd\cyra\cyrt\cyra\ \cyro\cyrb\cyrr\cyra\cyrshch\cyre\cyrn\cyri\cyrya}" }
         { curlanguage "german" =
            { "{online; abgerufen}" }
            { "language is not defined: " language "urldate" * * warning$ "online; accessed" }
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.techreport} % rename to bbl.techreport
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "Rep." }
   { curlanguage "german" =
      { "Bericht" }
      { curlanguage "russian" =
         { "{\cyr\CYRO\cyrt\cyrch\cyre\cyrt}" }
         { "language is not defined: " language "techrep" * * warning$ "Rep." }
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.mthesis}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "Master's thesis" }
   { curlanguage "german" =
      { "Diss.~Mag." }
      { curlanguage "russian" =
        { "{\cyr\CYRK\cyrv\cyra\cyrl\cyri\cyrf\cyri\cyrk\cyra\cyrc\cyri"
          "\cyro\cyrn\cyrn\cyra\cyrya\ \cyrr\cyra\cyrb\cyro\cyrt\cyra\ " *
          "\cyrm\cyra\cyrg\cyri\cyrs\cyrt\cyrr\cyra}" * }
         { "language is not defined: " language "mthesis" * * warning$ "Master's thesis" }
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.phdthesis}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "Ph.\,D. thesis" }
   { curlanguage "german" =
      { "Diss.~Ph.\,D." }
      { curlanguage "russian" =
         { "{\cyr\CYRD\cyri\cyrs\cyrs\ldots\ \cyrk\cyra\cyrn\cyrd\cyri"
           "\cyrd\cyra\cyrt\cyra\ \cyrn\cyra\cyru\cyrk}" * }
         { curlanguage "french" =
           { "Th\`{e}se de doctorat" }
           { "language is not defined: " language "phdthesis" * * warning$ "Ph.\,D. thesis" }
         if$}
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.dscithesis}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "Dr.\,Sci. dissertation" }
   { curlanguage "german" =
      { "Diss.~Dr." }
      { curlanguage "russian" =
         { "{\cyr\CYRD\cyri\cyrs\cyrs\ldots\ \cyrd\cyro\cyrk\cyrt\cyro"
           "\cyrr\cyra\ \cyrn\cyra\cyru\cyrk}" * }
         { "language is not defined: " language "dscithesis" * * warning$ "Dr.\,Sci. dissertation" }
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.nnoaddress}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "S.\ l." }
   { curlanguage "russian" =
      { "{\cyr\CYRB.\ \cyrm.}" }
      { "language is not defined: " language "nnoaddress" * * warning$ "S.\ l." }
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.nopublisher}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "s.\ n." }
   { curlanguage "russian" =
      { "{\cyr\cyrb.\ \cyri.}" }
      { "language is not defined: " language "nnopublisher" * * warning$ "s.\ n." }
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.nnopublisher}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "S.\ n." }
   { curlanguage "russian" =
      { "{\cyr\CYRB.\ \cyri.}" }
      { "language is not defined: " language "nnopublisher" * * warning$ "S.\ n." }
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.medium.text}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "Text" }
   { curlanguage "russian" = curlanguage "ukrainian" = or
      { "{\cyr\CYRT\cyre\cyrk\cyrs\cyrt}" }
      { "language is not defined: " language "medium" * * warning$ "Text" }
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.medium.elres}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "Electronic resource" }
   { curlanguage "russian" =
      { "{\cyr\CYREREV\cyrl\cyre\cyrk\cyrt\cyrr\cyro\cyrn\cyrn\cyrery\cyrishrt\ \cyrr\cyre\cyrs\cyru\cyrr\cyrs}" }
      { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
        { "{\cyr\CYRE\cyrl\cyre\cyrk\cyrt\cyrr\cyro\cyrn\cyrn\cyri\cyrishrt\ \cyrr\cyre\cyrs\cyru\cyrr\cyrs}" }
        { "language is not defined: " language "medium" * * warning$ "Electronic resource" }
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.chief}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "chief" }
   { curlanguage "russian" =
      { "\cyrr\cyru\cyrk." }
      { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
        { "\cyrr\cyru\cyrk." }
        { "language is not defined: " language "chief" * * warning$ "chief" }
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.executor}
{ curlanguage "english" =
   { "Executor" }
   { curlanguage "russian" =
      { "{\cyr\cyri\cyrs\cyrp\cyro\cyrl\cyrn.}" }
      { curlanguage "ukrainian" =
        { "{\cyr\cyrv\cyri\cyrk\cyro\cyrn\cyra\cyrv\cyre\cyrc\cyrsftsn}" }
        { "language is not defined: " language "medium" * * warning$ "Executor" }
      if$}
   if$}
if$}

FUNCTION {bbl.medium}
{ type$ "online" =
   { bbl.medium.elres }
   { bbl.medium.text  }
if$}

INTEGERS { nameptr namesleft numnames }


FUNCTION {format.names}
{
  #1 "{vv~}{ll}{~jj}{,~f.}" format.name$
}


FUNCTION {format.names.rev}
{
  's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      %"{f.}{~vv}{~ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      "{ff}{~vv}{~ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        { nameptr #4 =
          numnames #4 > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { t "others" =
          t "~others" =
          or
                { " " * bbl.etal * }
                { ", " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}


FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names emphasize}
  if$
}


FUNCTION {format.bookauthors}
{ bookauthor empty$
    { "" }
    { bookauthor format.names}
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors.after}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { author format.names.rev}
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.bookauthors.after}
{ bookauthor empty$
    { "" }
    { bookauthor format.names.rev}% always cuts to 4 persons
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.editors.after}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.edby "\ " * editor format.names.rev * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chief.after}
{ editor empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.chief "\ " * editor format.names.rev * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.executor.after}
{ author empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.executor ": " * author format.names.rev * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.compiler.after}
{ compiler empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.cmplr "\ " * compiler format.names.rev * }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title empty$
    { "" }
    { title "t" change.case$ }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year empty$
    { month empty$
        { "" }
        { "there's a month but no year in " cite$ * warning$
          month
        }
      if$
    }
    { month empty$
        'year
        { year ". " quote$ "--- " month * * * * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.address.publisher}
{
  address empty$
    'skip$
    { address output
      publisher empty$
        'skip$
        { new.column }
      if$
    }
  if$
  publisher output
}

FUNCTION {output.address.publisher.date}
{
  output.address.publisher
  format.date output
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem" write$
  cite$ bracify write$
  newline$
  language empty$
    { "english" 'curlanguage := }
    { language  'curlanguage := }
  if$
  "\selectlanguageifdefined" curlanguage bracify * write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{ 't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: instead of editing the PDF you can edit the `.bbl` file. it is a plain text file and you can open it with any text editor. The `.bbl` is rewritten every time `bibtex` is run.

Answer (score 2):

The formatting of the author's names is controlled by the function `format.names.rev` in the provided `bst` file.

Currently the function includes the following lines

```
  %"{f.}{~vv}{~ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  "{ff}{~vv}{~ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

To achieve the desired effect (i.e., initials followed by period) one has to uncomment the first of the above two lines, and comment the second; namely:

```
  "{f.}{~vv}{~ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
  %"{ff}{~vv}{~ll}{, jj}" format.name$ 't :=
```

Finally, it is better to make a copy of the `bst` file, rename it, modify it and use the new file.